# Does double ended fatty acid exist?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, fats

A fatty acid consists of a carbon chain, with a carboxylic acid on one end, and just a hydrogen on the other.

Does a substance with two carboxylic acid ends and no hydrogen end exist?

Comment: I'm not sure this is compatible with the site topic. (It's from scientific curiosity,  not for homework. And relief of scientific curiosity may not be a valid "actual problem".)

Comment: Plenty of them, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adipic_acid, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sebacic_acid

Comment: Yes and they are called bolaamphiphiles or bolaphiles